# How to requeue message in RabbitMQ using Sneakers gem with count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, sneakers

Now I'm publishing two messages in two different queues, the problem that they are dependent on each other, I have to make sure that I got the message from queue no.1 before the message of queue no.2, so I decided to requeue the queue2 message if the data needed from queue1 is not there yet 
 with maximum requeue times (for example three times) if not I will reject it.

now I have a problem in keep track of the requeues count, I've read to edit the headers with the tries number and then send it back to the queue, but I dont think requeue! method takes any arguments so it just requeue the same old message as it is, so anybody could help me with that?